# Which version is my SDK-X PHP Composer package?

Tags: php, composer-php

So I did composer update and now my dependencies updated to the latest version.

I have a copy of my repo locally with the same vendor dependency - how do I find out what exact version this package is so I can update my composer.json to pull the older working version?

Answer (score 0):

Guess the answer is:

```
composer show -i
```